# Apache Solr: Merging documents from two sources before indexing

Tags: solr4

I need to index data from a custom application in Solr. The custom app stores metadata in an Oracle RDBMS and documents (PDF, MS Word, etc.) in a file store. The two are linked in the sense that the metadata in the database refers to a physical document (PDF) in the file store.

I am able to index the metadata from the RDBMS without issues. Now I would like to update the indexed documents with an additional field  in which I can store the parsed content from the PDFs.

I have considered and tried the following
1. Using Update RequestHandler to try and update the indexed document with . This didn't work and the original document indexed from the RDBMS was overwritten.
2. Using SolrJ to do atomic updates but I am not sure if this is a good approach for something like this

Has anyone come across this issue before and what would be the recommended approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the document, but it requires that you know the id of the existing document. For example:

```
{
    "id": "5",
    "parsed_content":{"set": "long text field with parsed content"}
}
```

Instead of just saying `"parsed_content":"something"` you have to wrap the value in `"parsed_content":{"set":"something"}` to trigger adding it to the existing document.

See https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22field.22 for documentation on how to work with multivalued fields etc.